# Struggling to get this push_back() function to work

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

I'm working on an assignment for my college class, and I'm struggling to figure out why code for my push_front() function works without fail, but my push_back() always gives:

"Exception thrown: read access violation. **st** was nullptr."

```
struct NodeDate
{
    int day, month, year; //Structure's data
    struct NodeDate* nextNode; //Pointer to point to next node

}*start; //Not sure why we do this, but all examples contain it

class LinkedListDate
{
public:
    //Prototype of member functions
    NodeDate* create_node(NodeDate);
    void push_front();
    void pop_front();
    void remove_front();
    void search();
    void display();
    LinkedListDate();
    void push_back();
    void remove_back();
    void pop_back();
};

LinkedListDate::LinkedListDate()
{
    start = NULL; //Our first created pointer will be set to NULL
}

NodeDate* LinkedListDate::create_node(struct NodeDate newDate) //Function that creates a new node and returns said node
{
    struct NodeDate* tempNode, *s;

    tempNode = new(struct NodeDate); //Reserving memory for our temp node



    if (tempNode == NULL) //If the node is empty
    {
        std::cout << "Memory not allocated " << std::endl;
        return 0;

    }
    else //Otherwise assign parameter node value to temporary node
    {
        tempNode->day = newDate.day;
        tempNode->month = newDate.month;
        tempNode->year = newDate.year;
        tempNode->nextNode = NULL; //Remember these are all values contained within the date struct

        return tempNode; //Return the node
    }
}

void LinkedListDate::push_front() //Function that will insert a node at the start of our linkedlist
{
    struct NodeDate* tempNode, *st, newNode;

    std::cout << "Enter the day: ";
    std::cin >> newNode.day;

    std::cout << "Enter the month: ";
    std::cin >> newNode.month;

    std::cout << "Enter the year: ";
    std::cin >> newNode.year;

    tempNode = create_node(newNode); //Creating a new node for date with the create_node function



    if (start == NULL) //Checks if the starting (Head) node is NULL then first node to insert
    {
        start = tempNode; //Start node points to our temporary node

        start->nextNode = NULL; //Assign null to start->next
    }
    else //Otherwise nodes are already available in the list
    {
        st = start; //Assign start to st

        start = tempNode; //Start points to temporary node

        start->nextNode = st; //Start next point to st
    }

    std::cout << "Element Inserted at beginning" << std::endl;

}

void LinkedListDate::push_back() //Function to insert a new node at the end of the linkedlist
{
    struct NodeDate* tempNode, *st, newNode;

    std::cout << "Enter the day: ";
    std::cin >> newNode.day;

    std::cout << "Enter the month: ";
    std::cin >> newNode.month;

    std::cout << "Enter the year: ";
    std::cin >> newNode.year;

    tempNode = create_node(newNode); //Creating a new node for date with the create_node function

    st = start;



    while (st->nextNode != NULL) //Move til we reach end of the list
    {
        st = st->nextNode; //Move to the next node
    }

    tempNode->nextNode = NULL; //Assign null to temporary node next



    st->nextNode = tempNode; //st next points to temporary node

    std::cout << "Element Inserted at last" << std::endl;

}
```

Again, push_front() works, but push_back() does not work (The program runs, but after inputting the date for the first node I get the exception.

I've been trying a lot of things, but I can't seem to figure out what exactly I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What if `start` is null? You never check.  Consider a [mcve] so we can see the order you are doing things in. You might also consider tracing through in a debugger so you can see exactly where it goes wrong. I'd also advise moving the input handling code into a function so you don't have it copy/pasted in more than one place.

Comment: `push_back` doesn't have the "empty list" handling that `push_front` does.

Comment: There are some C-idioms here: In C++, `new` does not return `NULL` if allocation fails. It throws an exception instead. So, checking for `NULL` is useless. In modern C++ you would say `nullptr` instead of `NULL`. You don't need to qualify a type with `struct` every time. Just say `tempNode = new NodeDate;`. It does not only reserve memory (like `malloc()`), but also initializes it (if you have a constructor). Finally, `new` is not a function. It is an operator. You don't need parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct NodeDate
{
//...
}*start;
```

is the same is

```
struct NodeDate
{
//...
};
NodeDate *start;
```

push_back will fail when the list is empty (i.e. start is null).

```
void LinkedListDate::push_back()
{
    //...
    tempNode = create_node(newNode);
    tempNode->nextNode = nullptr;
    if(start == nullptr)
    {
        start = tempNode;
    }
    else
    {
        st = start;
        while (st->nextNode != nullptr) //Move til we reach end of the list
        {
            st = st->nextNode; //Move to the next node
        }
        st->nextNode = tempNode;
    }
    std::cout << "Element Inserted at last" << std::endl;
}
```